# Best way to make a return propagate

Tags: c#, return, execution

I couldn't find a answer to this, probably because I'm not asking this question in a proper way.

So, I'm writting a method that is inside a class, and at some point I want it to test for the formatting of a string. If it is not correct, I want it to show a message to the user, and to stop the execution, so that the user can fix that mistake. I have this:

```
                if (Is not properly formated)
                {
                    //get error information

                    //show error box with the formation error line
                    MessageBox.Show(String.Format(
                        "Error message{0}",
                        errorLine.ToString()), "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Stop);
                    return; 
                }
```

Of course, this will stop the execution of this method, but I want to stop the execution of the main method (a button click method).

What is the best way to do this in C#?

Comment: There are no multi-level returns. You could throw an `Exception`... but I don't suggest it

Comment: You could return a boolean or integer and then check the value of that inside the button-click method.

Comment: Why don't you think an exception might be good? Too agressive?I though about returning a value, but what if this specific method is buried inside another, and another, and another? Each one has to also return a value, isn't there a cleaner way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write a validation method that returns `true` if the value is valid, and optionally return a `string` telling what is wrong:

```
private bool Validate(string s, out string error)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(s))
    {
        error = "s is null";
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        error = null;
        return true;
    }
}
```

Then call it:

```
string error;
if (!Validate(null, out error))
{
    MessageBox.Show(error);

    // Do something
}
```

Instead of the `string` you could use an `enum` if you want to structure the list of possible errors.

Comment: That would work of course, but what if my method executes inside other and other and other methods? Each one of the calling method must test for the error to make the return propagate to the last calling method, so that execution will stop (the button click method). I think this gets quite annoying fast no?

Comment: You could opt to split the validation from the rest of the execution.

Comment: Otherwise exceptions as in the other answer could help.

Answer (score 2):

You should really be using exceptions in C#, for example

```
private void Calculate(string[] lines)
{
    try
    {
        lines.ForEach(Validate);

        // process lines
    }
    catch(InvalidArgumentException ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(...);
    }   
}

private void Validate(string s)
{
    if(s.IsNullOrEmpty)
        throw new InvalidArgumentException(/* some details here*/);
}
```

Comment: Throwing an exception should reflect a state that should not occur. I think returning a bool would be a better approach. No?

Comment: @ScottNimrod I am trying to follow defensive programming. Users aren't suppose to type: `'); drop table payrol; --`, but they do